# When calculating delta, should you recalculate vol?

Tags: greeks

Delta is the rate of change of price to the spot.

If the spot changes, so does the vol, so if you wanted to e.g. calculate delta as a finite difference

$$\frac{f(spot+h)-f(spot-h)}{2h}$$

would you recalculate a new volatility for the spots $spot - h$ and $spot + h$, or just ignore it?

Same question regarding calculating theta...

Comment: This boils down to sticky strike / sticky delta, no? http://deltaquants.com/volatility-sticky-strike-vs-sticky-delta

Comment: Isn't the definition of a partial derivative that all other variables/parameters are kept constant?

Comment: But I agree with @Kermittfrog that in a discrete setting, when you cannot ignore $h$ (i.e. it is not infinitesimal) anymore it boils down to sticky strike or sticky delta.

Comment: @ilovevolatility, i would argue that even in a infinitesimal setting you should incorporate the total effect, i.e. $\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} = \frac{\partial C(S,\sigma(S))}{\partial S}=\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}+\frac{\partial C}{\partial \sigma}\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial S}$ .

Comment: @Kermittfrog Yes, you are absolutely right, although what you wrote is still consistent with what I wrote about "keeping all other variables/parameters constant", i.e. you need to differentiate to $S$ only, but then also the volatility if it depends on $S$. But I am unnecessarily confuscating things. Bottom-line for OP: apologies, I may have had one beer to many, pls see Kermittfrog's answer/comment.

Comment: Thank you, both.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for the *total effect* of a (small) change in the underlying value on the option price, which is

$$
dO=\frac{\partial O}{\partial S}dS+\frac{\partial O}{\partial \sigma}\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial S}dS
$$

Effectively, this boils down to whether you want to apply, i.e. **model** a [sticky-delta or sticky-strike](http://deltaquants.com/volatility-sticky-strike-vs-sticky-delta) rule. Other sources are [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatility_smile#Evolution:_Sticky) and  [Derman](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Esmirnov/Derman.pdf)

**Sticky Strike** implies that the implied volatility is a function of the strike level $K$, only and there should be no change due to a sensitivity w.r.t. implied volatility (vega). With a **sticky delta** assumption, you would see a vega effect.

I am afraid that this boils down to a modeling assumption on your part...